# Linux Kernel Module development compile for other kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm using LinK+ in other to develop a linux kernel module. My development machine has a Linux Mint 18 installed operating system with kernel version 4.4.xx. For testing I want to deploy the kernel module to a Debian machine(in a virtualbox) which has a kernel version 3.16.xx.

LinK+ has an option called "Compile for other kernel" (see image below)

[image]

When I press that button a dialog ask me to point to Kernel Source Location. I've downloaded kernel version 3.16.xx from https://www.kernel.org/ and then pointed to extracted files from that archive.

The output of the make command is this:

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project VMDD ****

make --makefile=Makefile --directory=KERN_SRC modules 
make: Entering directory '/home/george/linkProjects/VMDD/KERN_SRC'
make -C /home/george/kernels/linux-3.16.43/ M=/home/george/linkProjects/VMDD/KERN_SRC modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/george/kernels/linux-3.16.43'

  WARNING: Symbol version dump ./Module.symvers
           is missing; modules will have no dependencies and modversions.

  CC [M]  /home/george/linkProjects/VMDD/KERN_SRC/VMDD.o
/bin/sh: 1: ./scripts/recordmcount: not found
scripts/Makefile.build:263: recipe for target '/home/george/linkProjects/VMDD/KERN_SRC/VMDD.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/george/linkProjects/VMDD/KERN_SRC/VMDD.o] Error 127
Makefile:1337: recipe for target '_module_/home/george/linkProjects/VMDD/KERN_SRC' failed
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/george/kernels/linux-3.16.43'
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/george/linkProjects/VMDD/KERN_SRC] Error 2
make: *** [modules] Error 2
Makefile:8: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: Leaving directory '/home/george/linkProjects/VMDD/KERN_SRC'
```

**What did I do wrong ?**

Comment: Note that if you make your module build with nix, then you can compile it with any kernel in nixpkgs as they provide `${kernel.dev}/lib/modules/${kernel.modDirVersion}/build` to access the built version. You can read more in the section "Out-of-tree kernel modules" in https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Linux_kernel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've downloaded kernel version 3.16.xx from https://www.kernel.org/ and then pointed to extracted files from that archive.

You can't compile modules for some kernel if you have only its original source. You need point IDE to configured and partially build kernel. Actually, all files needed to build modules for some kernel version are in kbuild directory of compiled kernel, installed into /lib/modules/*version*/kbuild. There are linux-kbuild-*version* (https://packages.debian.org/jessie/kernel/linux-kbuild-3.16) package with some files https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/linux-kbuild-3.16/filelist and linux-headers-*version* (https://packages.debian.org/jessie/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64) which includes Module.symvers (https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64/filelist):

> /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-4-amd64/Module.symvers

Comment: how can I "configure and partially build kernel" without replacing my current kernel ?

Comment: George02, I don't know the LinK+ IDE and its requirements for directory pointed to other kernel. I know packages in Debian which contain all files needed to build kernel modules locally (updated answer with 2 package names; they allow local build of kernel modules with https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt `make -C /lib/modules/__VERSION__/build M=$PWD`). They are installed in different dirs and I don't know how to copy and organize them into single directory for LinK+.

Comment: @George02, just install modules needed to build the module inside your virtual Debian and: build module in the virtual machine with `make -C /lib/modules/\`uname -r\`/build M=$PWD` and  `make -C /lib/modules/\`uname -r\`/build M=$PWD modules_install`; or check what is inside `/lib/modules/\`uname -r\`/build` directory and recursively (with link following) copy it to the host machine, then point to copy in LinK+.

Comment: Yup :)) silly me. I could build the module inside my VM.